# How to develop mobile apps in Zend Studio 10

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I am new to Zend Studio. I don't know how to work with version 10 version to create iPhone and Android mobile applications. Do you have any tutorial or sample code please?

Comment: Hi there. This sort of question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, since it is very easily web-searchable, and no prior effort appears to have been expended on it. Questions are best focussing on _specific_ programming problems you are having, such as "How do I get this WidgetContainer to render a Thingy when a IncredibleEvent is triggered?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio is a Version of Eclipse, specialized for PHP and the Zend Framework. Those are targeted at Web-Applications on PHP running Webservers.

You should be able to add the Android SDK and Eclipse Plugin for it and develop Android Apps (Java) on it but I highly recommend using pure Eclipse for it.

As far as I know, you can only develop iOS Apps on xCode on a Mac.

http://www.eclipse.org/

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: This answer assumes you are developing native apps for iOS/Android. if you want to create hybrid apps (webpages in a phone specific container app) you still need a non Zend editor but also the appropriate Container Software (for example PhoneGap or Appcellerator)

Answer (score 4):

plz Ref Following  URL  Easy Connect The You Moblie  to Zend  Studio

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4nmRO9-gN4